# Shell file permissions denied when running Docker

Tags: docker, shell, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm attempting to start a local Kafka broker but the error shows that permissions are denied when trying to execute a shell script.
When I run `docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up` I see the following error `Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./create-kafka-topic.sh": permission denied: unknown`.

```
version: "3"

services:
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER://:9092,LISTENER_HOST://:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER://kafka:9092,LISTENER_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

  schema-registry:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    links:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper

  kafka-topics-creator:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.init-kafka.yml
      cache_from:
        - confluentinc/cp-kafka
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

The `Dockerfile.init-kafka.yml` file contains the following:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka

WORKDIR /usr/bin
COPY scripts/create-kafka-topics.sh create-kafka-topic.sh

RUN chmod 777 create-kafka-topic.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./create-kafka-topic.sh"]
```

and `create-kafka-topics.sh` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add the topic you want to create in KAFKA_TOPICS below
# Make sure to prepend the topic with "dev."
KAFKA_TOPICS=("dev.event.this.is.my.kafka.event")

kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list

echo "Start creating default topics..."

for topic in "${KAFKA_TOPICS[@]}"
do
  kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
    --create \
    --if-not-exists \
    --topic "${topic}" \
    --partitions 1 \
    --replication-factor 1 \
    --config "cleanup.policy=compact"
  echo "Created topic ${topic}."
done

echo "All topics have been created!"
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list
```

I've tried doing `chmod +x` on the shell script and it shows that I have the correct permissions but something is telling me the Docker container itself doesn't have access to run the shell script?

Comment: You almost never want to use 777 permissions. You can also set permission while copying or even make it executable outside of docker. It will remain executable. `COPY --chmod=755 script.sh /script.sh`. That said, the way you do it should also work, so I assume the issue is something else.

Comment: @TheFool so in my Dockerfile.init-kafka.yml file remove the `RUN` line and update the `COPY` line to `COPY --chmod=755 scripts/create-kafka-topics.sh create-kafka-topic.sh`?

Comment: you can do that, but I dont think its the issue. Its just a little more clean. You can also add `--chown=appuser:appuser`. This appuser may the reason for some issues here. Although normally the commands while building are run as the user, so it should be already owned by the user. Anyway, I would go inside the container and trouble shoot from inside.

Comment: @TheFool I added that inside the docker init file but still same issues. I'm still fairly new to using Docker more than just running a few commands so I'll have to figure out how I can debug from inside the container.

Comment: you can build it and then run it interactively. `docker build -t debug -f Dockerfile.init-kafka.yml .` and then `docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash debug`

Comment: or you put `entrypoint: [sleep, infinity]` in your compose file, and then you use `docker exec` to go inside. So you have the other containers for testing.

Comment: looks like the first command worked fine and the second command allowed me to go inside the container. Not sure what I'm looking for with the second command though?

Comment: you want to investigate why the script isnt running. Check the file permissions, try to execute it, check if its in the right place and so on.

Comment: I think I got it! I ran `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache` then ran `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up`. All good to go!

Comment: ah, thats also a common gotcha with compose, yes. It won't automatically rebuild the image. You can also do `docker composer up --build` to force a rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the *correct* answer to this general issue but I was able to fix this issue with the following:

`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache`
and
`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up`.

Comment: You can remove `-f docker-compose.yml` since that is the default file. Also, you probably want `docker compose up --build`